# Passing generic class name in dbcontext

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

My entities context file code:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    //dbset 1
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    //dbset 2
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Class Shipments has a method GetCustomerName

```
public class Shipments
{
    public string GetName(object caller, System.Data.Entity.DbSet objectContext)
    {
        //This one passes.

        IQueryable<Customer> myCustomer = from p in objectContext
                                          select p where p.Id=1; //get customer name

        //This one fails
        IQueryable<caller.GetType()> myCustomer = from p in objectContext
                                                  select p where p.Id=1; //get customer name
    }
}
```

Question: I would like to remove the hard coding of class Customer there, instead call this method by passing the class name as parameter?

How can I implement this? In this case `caller.GetType().Name` didn't work for me.

```
GetName(Order, mydbContext);
GetName(Customer, mydbContext);
```

Both should work with the same code (trying it to make generic, I am not sure how to cast it generic). Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: You will at least need a base type that has `Id` and `Name` properties.  Even then you will need a switch or generics to determine which property of your context to query.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of passing an `object` argument just for the sake of getting its type. You can use generics for that:

```
public string GetName<T>(DbSet objectContext) where T : BaseEntity {
    IQueryable<T> myCustomer = from p in objectContext
                               select p where p.Id = 1;
    //Get the name
    //Return the name
}
```

Please note that I added a constraint for `T` to extend from a `BaseEntity`.

All your entities should then extend from this abstract class (which should contain the property `Id` and `Name` for getting the name).

You would then be able to retrieve the name of, not only `Customer` entities, but even `Order` entities:

```
string customerName = GetName<Customer>(context);
string orderName = GetName<Order>(context);
```

---

If only your `Customer` entity has the property `Name`, then don't use generics at all, you would be better defining the type explicitly:

```
public string GetName(context) {
    IQueryable<Customer> customer = from p in context
                                    select p where p.Id = 1;
    //Get the name
    //Return the name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so many people, including myself early on, you are not seeing the difference between a data type and an instance of the `Type` class.  A data type is something that is known at compile time.  When you call `GetType`, what you get back is an object whose data type is `Type`.  It contains information about a data type but it is not a data type itself.

What you need to do is make your `GetName` method generic as well:

```
public string GetName<T>(T caller, System.Data.Entity.DbSet objectContext)
{
    IQueryable<T> myEntity = from p in objectContext
                             select p where p.Id=1; //get customer name
}
```

To be able to do that though, the compiler must know that type `T` actually has an `Id` property.  That means that `T` has to be constrained to be a specific base class or interface that declares an `Id` property.  In the case of auto-generated EF classes, an interface is your only option.

There are still other issues with your code, but that covers what you are actually asking about.

Comment: I would say there is a difference between generic type-parameters and method parameters.

Comment: @jwize, and you'd be right, but I don't think I implied otherwise so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: That comment was just meant to give light to the word type-parameter  which people can look up online. Nothing too wrong with your answer.